# rabbitmq with wamp server

Tags: php, wamp, rabbitmq, pecl

Ok so I have seen other questions regarding this but I still havent come right.

I need to connect to rabbitmq from php but I am using wamp on my windows machine.

I have seen that I need to download a pecl .dll. I have download a few but I still cant get it working.

Has anyone got this working if they have please tell me how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at AMQP PHP Extension?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/amqp.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

This can be very easily achieved with [php-amqplib](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib) .

> This library is a pure PHP implementation of the AMQP protocol. It's been tested against RabbitMQ.
>
> Requirements: PHP 5.3 due to the use of namespaces.

And thus it works perfectly on windows too :)